# Is my proof using circular logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

$$\forall x, y \in \mathbb{Z},    x^2 + y^2 -3  \not\equiv \ 0\ (mod \ 4)$$
I'm not certain if this is how I can show x and y squared will never be equal to 3. This is what I came up with:

My proof:
$$\ 0\ (mod \ 4) = 0$$
Considering x and y ∈ ℤ

$$x^2 + y^2  \neq  \ 3 \ \ since  \ x \ and \ y \ are \ squared$$
So,

$$x^2 + y^2 -3  \not\equiv \ 0\ (mod \ 4)$$

End of Proof

Comment: Why is this true? Try $x=1,y=2$.

Comment: @David Cheng Oh woops I wrote 5 when I meant to write 3

Comment: This is totally incomprehensible and fails to comprehend the meaning of modular arithmetic.

Comment: Now how did you get $x^2+y^2\not =3$?

Comment: Well since x and y are squared integers, any integers for x and y will not be equal to 3.

Comment: But then we have for example $5\not=1$, but $5\equiv1\mod 4$. Then your logic on the next part doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not even circular. It is wrong. What do you mean by 0(mod 4) = 0. Try to prove in this way: The square numbers are always of the form. 4k or 4k+1. Thus, try three possible cases and conclude your "proposition".